# Custom Hook receiving a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a `Custom Hook`. In this hook, I receive a Promise from `loadRates()`:

```
export const actions = {
  updateRate: () =>
    loadRates()
      .then(response => ({
        type: types.UPDATE_RATE,
        value: response
      }))
      .catch(reject => ({
        type: types.ERROR_UPDATE_RATE,
        value: reject
      }))
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_RATE:
      return { ...state, rates: action.value, loading: false };
    case types.ERROR_UPDATE_RATE:
      return { ...state, error: action.value, loading: false };
    default:
      throw new Error("Action type must be defined");
  }
};
```

The problem is that even if I have a `response` from the `loadRates()`, I receive a `Action type must be defined` error, because my `state` is `pending`.

What should I do to correct this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6pk73rlyp)

Comment: Where is your custom hook?

Comment: I think you missed defining action.type for your action.  It's a question regarding redux action and not for react-hooks or promises so far as I can tell

Comment: This is my custom hook. The problem is that it doesn't wait the `actions` and goes to the `reducer`. So, since my `state` is `pending`, it throws the error. The `action.type` is defined in the `export const actions`, inside the `loadRates().then` and `loadRates().catch`

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle out of it?

Comment: Okay, will do it!

Comment: @kushalvm here it is: https://codesandbox.io/embed/z6pk73rlyp

Comment: Reducer shouldn't throw error but return state as it is in default condition. I modified it. Rest of the code leads to more errors.

Comment: Requires a lot of work in terms of store usage, react + redux usage. Hooks is not really a custom hook the way it should be. Lot of work my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `dispatch` function from `useReducer` coming from `Store.js` is called with a Promise, the return of `actions.updateRate` in `ratesReducer.js`.

This `dispatch` parameter must be an object with a type property (it's the same in redux). One way to solve your issue, would be to dispatch when the promise resolves or rejects. In redux, you can use a thunk, there's a library for that. That being said, I will explicit how a thunk works so you have a better overview.
Let's enhance the basic dispatch, and feed it to the context provider:

```js
export const StoreProvider = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const thunkDispatch = action => {
    if (typeof action === "function") {
      return action(dispatch);
    }

    return dispatch(action);
  };

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ state, actions, dispatch: thunkDispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Your async actions can now be functions that take dispatch as parameter.

```js
const updateRate = dispatch => // get dispatch from parameters
  loadRates()
    .then(response => dispatch({ // add dispatch here
      type: types.UPDATE_RATE,
      value: response
    }))
    .catch(reject => dispatch({ // add dispatch here too
      type: types.ERROR_UPDATE_RATE,
      value: reject
    }))
```

Here is the pen updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/3qx982292p.
Have a look at redux-thunk, this problem isn't new and there is a lot of knowledge for it already.